# What does this code mean and do?

Tags: list, prolog

I am completely new to Prolog and I can't understand this piece of code. How would you read these 4 clauses? What do they do?

```
a([]). 
a([_|L]):-b(L).

b([_]).
b([_|L]):-a(L).
```

Thank you.

Comment: Run some queries in the [tag:prolog-toplevel]! Queries like `?- a(Xs).` or `?- b(Xs).`...

Comment: It appears to succeed when you have lists with an even number of elements.

Comment: @Enigmativity it depends upon which predicate you mean. `a` succeeds on even lists, and `b` succeeds on odd ones. It does so inefficiently (succeeds twice in almost all cases for any given list).

Comment: @lurker - You're right.

Comment: @lurker: "almost", that's true only for `a([])`

Comment: @false - yeah that's what I meant by *almost*. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @repeat suggested in his comment, run a general query, and here's what you get:

```
| ?- a(Xs).

Xs = [] ? ;

Xs = [_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

And:

```
| ?- b(Xs).

Xs = [_] ? ;

Xs = [_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

So `a(Xs)` succeeds if `Xs` is a list containing an even number of elements, and `b(Xs)` succeeds if `Xs` is a list containing an odd number of arguments. As you can see, `a/1` and `b/1` succeed twice in each case except `a([]).` which succeeds only once. So it is not an efficient predicate for determining list length parity.

Let's rewrite these with more descriptive names:

```
even([]).
even([_|L]) :- odd(L).
odd([_]).
odd([_|L]) :- even(L).
```

Now let's "read" what they say:

1. `[]` is an even list
2. `[_|L]` is an even list if `L` is an odd list
3. `[_]` is an odd list
4. `[_|L]` is an odd list if `L` is an even list

These sound logical, but why do `even/1` and `odd/1` succeed twice with the exception of `even([])`? If you look at the definition of `odd/1`, there are two ways for `[_]` to succeed. One is via the `odd([_]).` clause. The second is by the second `odd/1`, since you would have:

```
odd([_|[]]) :- even([]).  % [_] == [_|[]]
```

Since both `even/1` and `odd/1` calls (with the exception of `even([]).`) eventually recurse down to a call to `odd([_])`, you'll get two solutions.

---

One way to eliminate the ambiguity in the logic is to refactor them a little. Consider the following recursive rules:

- A list of at least 2 elements has an even number of elements if the tail of the list, after the first 2, is also even.
- A list of at least 2 elements has an odd number of elements if the tail of the list, after the first 2, is also odd.

Translating these rules to Prolog, including the base cases as before:

```
even([]).
even([_,_|L]) :- even(L).
odd([_]).
odd([_,_|L]) :- odd(L).
```

Now the results will be:

```
| ?- even(Xs).

Xs = [] ? ;

Xs = [_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

And

```
| ?- odd(Xs).

Xs = [_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_] ? ;

Xs = [_,_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

Following CapelliC's suggestion of using a DCG, similar rules can be written:

```
even --> [] | [_,_], even.
odd --> [_] | [_,_], odd.
```

With results:

```
| ?- phrase(even, L).

L = [] ? ;

L = [_,_] ? ;

L = [_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

And

```
| ?- phrase(odd, L).

L = [_] ? ;

L = [_,_,_] ? ;

L = [_,_,_,_,_] ? ;
...
```

---

Following @false's suggestion, an even more direct "fix" to the original code would be to eliminate the redundant base case for `odd([_]).` since it's already covered by the base case for `even([]).` This is also a little simpler than the above solution since it takes advantage of the interdependency between the `even/1` and `odd/1` predicates (in the above solution, `even/1` and `odd/1` stand on their own).

```
even([]).
even([_|L]) :- odd(L).
odd([_|L]) :- even(L).
```

Or, in DCG:

```
even --> [] | [_], odd.
odd --> [_], even.
```

Comment: And the conclusion? You leave it unsaid!!

Comment: @false - I answered the OP's two questions (*How would you read these 4 clauses?* and *What do they do?*) completely, I believe. I was going to elaborate on a better way to determine parity of the size of the list, but it wasn't clear to me that's what the OP was after based upon the specific wording of the questions.

Comment: There is a much simpler way to remove redundancy! Just remove `b([_]).`

Comment: Thank you so much for the extended and comprehensive answer!!

Comment: @SiaNravoha you're quite welcome, and I'm glad it helped. If you find my answer acceptable, you can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

the argument schema is important:

a) the list is clearly a counter, since we never consider the content.

b) just a suggestion: read logic as *productions*, or as DCG

```
a-->[];[_],b.
b-->[_];[_],a.
```

to be called - for instance

```
?- phrase(a, [w,h,a,t]).
```